My shell script refuses to exit with the proper code
I have a shellscript that needs to exit with code 1 when any of its steps fail, in order to prevent the subsequent script from running.
But in the logs, i see the exit code is always 0, and the next shellscript starts anyway.
I tried:
#!/bin/bash
set -e

and
<<command execution>>
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then { echo "Failed" ; exit 1; } fi

But the logs always state that the exit code is 0
Why can't i make the script exit with code 1 ? Could there be some shell code setting that is preventing the shell script from exiting with non-zero code ?

Test your scripts as shellcheck.net then post your complete corrected script so that we can try to duplicate the problem you're having.

Obviously, your command terminated with exit code 0, so there was no non-zero exit code to be intercepted. If you believe otherwise, create an example script which demonstrates the problem. You can use the commands false and true to simulate actual applications, which would return exit code 1 or 0.

set -e stops the program immediately if a pipeline (or a command) exits with a non-zero status.
So, if your <<command execution>> exits with a non-zero, the rest of the program is not executed and never executes exit 1 in your if ... then ... fi statement.
3 solutions:

Remove -e just before command execution and add -e just after its return code read

set +e
command_execution
ret_cmd_exec=$?
set -e
if [[ $ret_cmd_exec -ne 0 ]; then ... fi


Read return code regardless of status

command_execution && ret_cmd_exec=$? || ret_cmd_exec=$?
ret_cmd_exec=$?
if [[ $ret_cmd_exec -ne 0 ]; then ... fi


Tests command execution in if statement

if ! command_execution; then ... fi

